# Haskell: Uncurry, Curry, composition

Tags: haskell, currying

I have a problem with understanding what the compiler does when I enter this:

```
(curry . uncurry) (+) 1 2
```

After my understanding the compiler goes with uncurry first which would mean that an error would occur because the uncurry function needs an input like this:

```
(curry . uncurry) (+) (1,2)
```

but obviously the first one is right. I don't get why though.

What exactly are the steps the compiler takes when evaluating this?

**Another** topic included question:
Why does

```
(uncurry . curry) (+) (1,2)
```

does not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> After my understanding the compiler goes with uncurry.

No it goes with the `(curry . uncurry)`

If we evaluate the `(curry . uncurry)` function we see that this short for:

```
\x -> curry (uncurry x)
```

so the `(curry . uncurry) (+) 1 2` function is short for:

```
(\x -> curry (uncurry x)) (+) 1 2
```

or thus:

```
(curry (uncurry (+))) 1 2
```

and [**`uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) and [**`curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:curry) thus transform a function. This thus means that `uncurry (+)` indeed expects a 2-tuple:

```
uncurry (+) :: Num a => (a, a) -> a
```

but now pass this function through the `curry` function:

```
curry (uncurry (+)) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

so the `curry` function undoes the transformation the `uncurry` made to the `(+)` function. This thus means that `curry (uncurry (+))` is the same as `(+)`, and thus:

```
(curry (uncurry (+))) 1 2
```

is equivalent to:

```
(+) 1 2
```

and this is thus equivalent to `3`.

The `curry . uncurry` is not completely equivalent to `id` however, since it has as type:

```
curry . uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> c
```

this thus means that it restricts the function to a function of type `a -> (b -> c)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression parses as

```
(((curry . uncurry) (+)) 1) 2
```

so, it builds the function `(curry . uncurry) (+)` and applies it to `1`, then the resulting function is applied to `2`.

Hence, we start from `(curry . uncurry) (+)` which means `curry (uncurry (+))`. Assume for simplicity that `(+)` is implemented as

```
(+) = \x y -> ...
```

Note the above is an curried function, taking `x` and then `y` as separate arguments. We then have:

```
curry (uncurry (+))
= { definition + }
curry (uncurry (\x y -> ...))    -- note the separate arguments
= { definition uncurry }
curry (\(x, y) -> ...)           -- only one pair argument
= { definition curry }
(\x y -> ...)                    -- back to two arguments
= { definition + }
(+)
```

Above, `uncurry` transforms the function `+` into one that accepts a single pair argument instead of two. This transformation is reversed by `curry`, which breaks the pair argument into two separate ones.

Indeed, `curry . uncurry` is the identity transformation on binary curried functions since it applies a transformation and its inverse. Hence, it has no effect on the result, or on the type of the functions involved.

We conclude that your expression is equivalent to `((+) 1) 2`, which evaluates to `3`.

Answer (score 1):

This question got great answers, yet I would like to add a note about `curry . uncurry`.

You might have heard of `SKI`-calculus. If you haven't, it is a calculus where we work with 3 combinators:

```
Sabc = ac(bc)
Kab  = a
Ia   = a
```

It is widely known to be Turing-full.

Besides, the `I` combinator is redundant. Let us try writing it down in terms of `S` and `K` combinators.
The main idea is that the only argument of I should be passed as the first argument of `K`, whose second argument is occupied. That is exactly what the `S` combinator does: if we pass `K` as the first argument of `S`, we would have it return the third argument of `S`:

```
SKbc = Kc(bc) = c
```

We have shown that (`K*ab = b`):

```
K* = SK
```

Therefore, we just need to choose the second argument: both `K` and `S` would do:

```
I = SKK = SKS
```

As one can see, combinator `I` corresponds to `id`;
combinator `K` corresponds to const;
and combinator `S` corresponds to `(<*>) :: (e -> a -> b) -> (e -> a) -> e -> b`.

`I = SKK` corresponds to `const <*> const :: a -> a`.
Our other results (`I = SKS` and `K* = SK`) do not hold in Haskell due to typing:

```
GHCi> :t (<*>) const (<*>) {- id -}
(<*>) const (<*>) {- id -}
  :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f (a -> b)

GHCi> :t (const <*>) {- flip const -}
(const <*>) {- flip const -} :: (b -> a) -> b -> b
```

As one can see, our implementations act as the required functions on their domain, but we narrowed the domains down.

If we specify `(<*>) const (<*>)` to the reader, we get exactly the function you wrote down as `curry . uncurry` - `id` for functions.

Another workalike for `curry . uncurry` is `($)`:

```
f $ x   = f x
($) f x = f x
($) f   = f
($)     = id
```

The function you found is very interesting - it might be a good exercise to look for other workalikes (I don't know whether there are any other notable ones out there).